# How to update a local table remotely?

Tags: kdb

I have a large table on a remote server with an unknown (millions) amount of rows of data. I'd like to be able to fetch the data in batches of 100,000 rows at a time, update my local table with those fetched rows, and complete this until all rows have been fetched. Is there a way I can update a local table remotely?

Currently I have a dummy table called `t` on the server along with the following variables...

```
t:([]sym:1000000?`A`B`Ab`Ba`C`D`Cd`Dc;id:1+til 1000000)
selector:select from t where sym like "A*"
counter:count selector
divy:counter%100000
divyUP:ceiling divy
```

and the below function on the client along with the variables `index` set to 0 and `normTable`, which is a copy of the remote table...

```
index:0
normTable:h"0#t"

batches:{[idx;divy;anty;seltr]
    if[not idx=divy;
    batch:select[(anty;100000)] from seltr;
    `normTable upsert batch;
    idx+::1;
    divy:divy;
    anty+:100000;
    seltr:seltr;
    batches[idx;divy;anty;seltr]];
    idx::0}
```

I call that function using the following command...

```
 batches[index;h"divyUP";0;h"selector"]
```

The problem with this approach though is `h"selector"` fetches all the rows of data at the same time (and multiple times - for each batch of 100,000 that it upserts to my local `normTable`).

I could move the `batches` function to the remote server but then how would I update my local `normTable` remotely?

Alternatively I could break up the rows into batches on the server and then pull each batch individually. But if I don't know how many rows there are how do I know how many variables are required? For example the following would work, but only up to the first 400k rows...

```
batch1:select[100000] from t where symbol like "A*"
batch2:select[100000 100000] from t where symbol like "A*"
batch3:select[200000 100000] from t where symbol like "A*"
batch4:select[300000 100000] from t where symbol like "A*"
```

Is there a way to set a `batchX` variable so that it creates a new variable that equals the count of `divyUP`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest few changes as you are trying to connect to remote server:

- Do not run synchronous request as that would make server to slow down its processing. Try to make asynchronous request using [callbacks](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/callbacks/).
- Do not do full table scan(for heavy comparison) in each call specially for regex. Its possible that most of the data might be available in cache in next call but still it is not guaranteed which will again impact the server normal operations.
- Do not make data requests in burst. Either use timer or make another data request call when last batch data has arrived.

Below approach is based on above suggestions. It will avoid scanning full  table for columns other than index column(which is light weight) and make next request only when last batch has arrived.

**Create Batch processing function**

This function will run on server and read small batch of data from table using indices and return the required data.

```
q) batch:{[ind;s] ni:ind+s; d:select from t where i within (ind;ni), sym like "A*"; 
                  neg[.z.w](`upd;d;$[ni<count t;ni+1;0]) }
```

It takes 2 arguments- starting index and batch size to work on.

This function will finally call `upd` function on local macine asynchronously and will pass 2 arguments.

- Table index to start next batch from (return 0 in case all rows are done to stop next batch processing)
- Data from current batch request

**Create Callback function**

Result from batch processing function will come into this function.

If index > 0 that means there is more data to process and next batch should start form this index.

```
q) upd:{[data;ind] t::t,data;if[ind>0;fetch ind]}
```

**Create Main function to start process**

```
q)fetch:{[ind] h (batch;ind;size)}
```

Finally open connection, create table variable and run `fetch` function.

```
q) h:hopen `:server:port
q) t:()
q) size:100
q) fetch 0
```

Now, above method is based on the assumption that server table is static. In case its getting updates in real time then changes would be required depending upon how the table is getting updated on server.

Also, other optimizations can be done depending upon attributes set on remote table which can improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul. I'm not so familiar with callbacks in kdb (researching it now). Do the callback function and main function live on both the client and server or are they only on the client or server?

Comment: All functions I have mentioned will be on client.  Callbacks normally are the function implementation on client side which other process call after completing the client request in asynchronous call. Other way of thinking of this is a publisher calling a function on subscriber whenever there is an update.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok sending sync messages it can be simplified to something like:

```
{[h;i]`mytab upsert h({select from t where i in x};i)}[h]each 0N 100000#til h"count t"
```

And you can easily change it to control the *number* of batches (rather than the size) by instead using `10 0N#` (that would do it in 10 batches)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having individual variables, the cut function can split up the result of the select into chunks of 100000 rows. Indexing each element is a table.

```
batches:100000 cut select from t where symbol like "A*"
```